# Replace and add at end of the line

Tags: vba, replace, ms-word

I need to replace some starting text with another one and add at the end another text. This is a starting example:

```
- This is a phrase that match
Another - Phrase
Yes another - one
- This also match
```

The result i want to have is:

```
$This is a phrase that match%
Another - Phrase
Yes another - one
$This also match%
```

So replace "- " with "$" (**only if is the first two character of the sentence**) and add at the end of the line, if match, "%"

I have search and the the replace function work but i don't know how to add the end of line:

```
With Selection.Find 
 .ClearFormatting 
 .Text = "- " 
 .Replacement.Text = "$" 
 .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True, Wrap:=wdFindContinue 
End With
```

I have see there is a InsetAfter method but it create a new line, or i have wrong implemented. Suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need a macro for this! All you need is a *wildcard* Find/Replace, where:

```
Find = ^13- ([!^13]@)^13
Replace = ^p$\1%^p
```

Comment: Don't seems to work. That replace every "-" and not only the one at starting line of the sentence. Thanks

Comment: Did you include the leading '- ' in your Find expression? If that's not the determining factor, how then is one supposed to know whether it's the «starting line of the sentence»? Every line in your post is a new sentence!

Comment: I have included. I have also posted the expectetd result, with your find/replace also the sentence `Another - Phrase` and `Yes another - one` will be modify and the "-" is not at start of the sentence but in the middle. Did you try your Find\Replace with my four sentences?

Comment: F/R expression updated.